# Wait until alamofire is done getting request and making object

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am having a problem with waiting until one object is made, then I wish to update my UI. If i run the function, it will instantly get the out of index error because its trying to get some text from the first object when it dosent exist yet... Anyone who could help me?

```
func getMovieData(activeGenreLink: String){

    //self.posterLoading.startAnimating()

        Alamofire.request(activeGenreLink).responseJSON { response in
            //print(response.request)  // original URL request
            //print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            //print(response.data)     // server data
            //print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            var test = 0
            self.movieArray = []


            if let json = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                if let movies = json["results"] as? [AnyObject]{
                    for movie in movies{
                        let movieObject: Movie = Movie()

                        let title = movie["title"] as? String
                        let releaseDate = movie["release_date"] as! String
                        let posterPath = movie["poster_path"] as! String
                        let overView = movie["overview"] as! String
                        let movieId = movie["id"] as! Int
                        let genre_ids = movie["genre_ids"] as! [AnyObject]

                        movieObject.title = title
                        movieObject.movieRelease = releaseDate
                        movieObject.posterPath = posterPath
                        movieObject.overView = overView
                        movieObject.movieId = movieId


                        for genre in genre_ids{//Genre ids, fix this
                            movieObject.movieGenre.append(genre as! Int)
                        }



                        self.movieArray.append(movieObject)


                    }//End of for each movie
                }

            }


    }//End of Json request



}//End of getmoviedata
```

Comment: Where are you trying this code? I mean, inside the viewDidLoad? or where?  Everything you do inside the closure `response in ` will be called once the alamofire request is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use completion block/closure.

```
func getMovieData(activeGenreLink: String,completion : ()->()){

    //self.posterLoading.startAnimating()

        Alamofire.request(activeGenreLink).responseJSON { response in
            //print(response.request)  // original URL request
            //print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            //print(response.data)     // server data
            //print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            var test = 0
            self.movieArray = []


            if let json = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                if let movies = json["results"] as? [AnyObject]{
                    for movie in movies{
                        let movieObject: Movie = Movie()

                        let title = movie["title"] as? String
                        let releaseDate = movie["release_date"] as! String
                        let posterPath = movie["poster_path"] as! String
                        let overView = movie["overview"] as! String
                        let movieId = movie["id"] as! Int
                        let genre_ids = movie["genre_ids"] as! [AnyObject]

                        movieObject.title = title
                        movieObject.movieRelease = releaseDate
                        movieObject.posterPath = posterPath
                        movieObject.overView = overView
                        movieObject.movieId = movieId


                        for genre in genre_ids{//Genre ids, fix this
                            movieObject.movieGenre.append(genre as! Int)
                        }



                        self.movieArray.append(movieObject)


                    }//End of for each movie
                }

            }

           completion()
    }//End of Json request

}
```

Finally call this method,

```
self.getMovieData(activeGenreLink: "your_link_here", completion: {
            //updateUI
})
```

**Why?**

Because Alamofire responseJSON is an asynchronous call. When you call your method `getMovieData` obviously it returns without waiting for responseJSON to finish. You need a completion handler to inform the VC which called `getMovieData` to inform the completion of it.

Because Alamofire responseJSON block is triggered on main thread, you can directly update the UI in the completion block without having to change the thread.

Comment: You must remember call the `completion()` closure :)

Comment: Dosent work, i still get the Index out of range error. And i am calling the completion block correctly @Sandeep-Bhandari

Comment: @Pr0tonion it must be because you are using the array before doing the request. If you are using a tableView remember that where you implement the method `numberOfRows`or `cellForIndex` you must review if your array is not null.

Comment: Try putting breakpoint inside responseJSON method and check if you are actually getting any data, if yes check the self.movieArray count. Where exactly is this crash occurring paste the code

Comment: @Aitor Pagán : Bingo

Comment: When i used breakpoints i found that as soon as the function is run it jumps straight to completion() @Sandeep-Bhandari

Comment: @pr0tonion : Check the value of response.result.value on console. and make sure as aitor said in his comment, not to update UI without data. My guess response.result.value might be nil

Comment: Thank you, the if statement worked! :D